# Sage Math: How to read input data for a graph from a file

Tags: graph-theory, math-software, sagemath

The help center seems to indicate that this topic is suited for here, as `software that mathematicians use`, apologies if this is incorrect.

So, I'm brand new to Sage, and I've only ever messed with a little Python. (I am an experienced programmer though.)

I'm trying to create a little example in Sage where I construct a graph (graph theory, not coordinate) by reading in a list of nodes and edges from a text file.

I'd like to take input in the following format, where every node name is given, followed by a space, the pipe character, a space, and then a comma spaced list of nodes to create edges to, e.g.:

```
A | B, C
B | A, J, G, K
C | A
...
J | B, Q
```

Acceptable methods would be either directly reading and parsing the input from a file stored somewhere, or pasting data from a text file into some kind of text box.

Comment: Personally I think it's more appropriate on stackoverflow or ask.sagemath.org, but luckily you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this should be easy (given your programming background).   Three steps.

1. Make all your vertices into strings, `"A"` instead of `A`.
2. Turn your list into a Python dictionary, where for each thing before the pipe you associate the list of connected vertices, e.g. `{"A":["B","C"]}` (except the dict should be all of these correspondences).
3. Turn it into a graph by doing `Graph(my_dict)`.

I think this should work, unless your connection lists are not consistent.  See [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzL0osyNCoVnJUsopWclLSUVByVooFkk4gviOI7wUi3EGEN1AGKA2WiK3VBACamg0L&lang=sage).

```
Graph({"A":["B", "C"], "B":["A", "J", "G", "K"],"C":["A"]})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[kcrisman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/24113/kcrisman) has a good answer (which I have accepted because it is correct, even though I prefer mine), but I ended up doing it differently.

First off, I started using a different format. I used a `.csv` file instead of a `.txt` file to store the data, and I removed the pipe character entirely; instead, I considered the first token in each row to be the header for that row.

For posterity, my code is here:

```
graph = Graph()
vertices = list()
edges = list()

def getDataFromFile():
    dataFile = open(raw_input('Enter name of csv data file to use:'), 'rt')
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(dataFile)
        for row in reader:
            for course in row:
                if (not course.strip() in vertices):
                    vertices.append(str(course).strip())
                if (not course == row[0]):
                    edges.append((row[0].strip(), course.strip()))
    finally:
        dataFile.close()          

getDataFromFile()
graph.add_vertices(vertices)
graph.add_edges(edges)
```

The real question is, why I am I even a Software Engineer when someone can do a month's worth of my work with like 6 lines of Python?

Comment: I bet you could do it with one line of Perl, if Perl supported plotting graphs (perhaps it does) - though no one else would be able to read that one line :)

Comment: If only I could find a Python Library to do my work for me and `return` a paycheck!